# Split multiple objects in one image and display them as separate images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working on a project of white blood cells detection.I got the following image after applying edge detection steps for white blood cell detection:
[image]

I want to display each cell (with white boundary) as a separate image, so far I have tried the following code:
Here imabord is the image given in the link.

```
r=regionprops(imabord, 'BoundingBox');
exTractedCell=imcrop(imabord,r.BoundingBox);
imshow(exTractedCell);
```

By applying this code I just got a cropped image of all cells; but I want to display all the cells separately as separate images.
Kindly help me to display all the detected cells as separate images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code which I think do what you want. I added the 'Area' property in order to reject cells too small. You can change the parameter of course. In the for-loop I commented a code used to create some kind of montage using subplots, if you would like to display all cells in one single figure.

```
close all
clear
clc

A = im2bw(imread('ImCells.jpg')); %// Read the image

r=regionprops(A, 'BoundingBox','Area');

r(1) = []; %// Clear 1st entry as it's the outside rectangle.

MaxArea = 40; %// Select largest area you want to keep.
r = r([r.Area] > MaxArea); %// Detect cells larger than some value.

L = length(r);

figure


%    hold all %// Use if you use the subplot command
for k = 1:L

    exTractedCell=imcrop(A,[r(k).BoundingBox]);

    imshow(exTractedCell)
    pause(0.01);
    %subplot(10,10,k); %//You could create a montage using subplots.
    %imshow(exTractedCell);

end
```

For instance using a maximal area of 20 and the subplots it gives something like this:
[image]

You can add some code in the loop to manipulate/do whatever you want with the cropped images then.

Hope that helps! If not please provide more details as to what you want.

Comment: actually i want to display all the cropped cell images in separate figures.for example if an image has 4 cells then i need these 4 cells to be displayed separately in 4 figures.

Comment: ok so is the code above doing the right thing? With the calls t imshow in the loop individual cell images should show up one at a time.

Comment: code works for this particular image but if i give some other image as input, nothing is displayed may be its because of max area condition.

Comment: Yep that's very likely. You can try without any restriction on the area as well; I just added it to clean up a bit. You can post other images if you want then I could check.

Comment: is there any way to automatically display the cells with white boundary one by one like first cell detected (at the same location which it occupied in the original image)  with a black background in a figure  regardless of the area, shape and number of cells in the original image

Comment: I guess so; using a for-loop with a hold on at the beginning, you could arrange to get the actual position of every given cell and overlay them on the original image. I must say I don't have time right now to do it but that could be an interesting question! I'll check later.